# AsString shows up as undeclared indentifier

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pascal

```pascal
function TDM1.fct_login(nom_util, mdp_util: string): boolean;
begin
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('@nom_util').AsString = 'John Smith';
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('@mdp_util').AsString = '524462';
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  Result := ADOQuery1.RecordCount = 1;
end;
```

An error message pops up saying

```
undeclared identifier: AsString
error code : E2003
```

I tried changing it to `AsValue`, same error!

Comment: Try .Value insted of .AsValue

Comment: [dcc64 Erreur] u_dm.pas(33): E2029 ':=' expected  but '=' found

Comment: In Delphi, when setting values use := , when doing comparisons use = so when setting your parameter values use :=

Answer (score 3):

The error is correct, but not the only error in your code.  Change your code to

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('@nom_util').Value := 'John Smith';
```

(the `=` may just have been a typo, in Delphi's Pascal, the assignment operator is `:=`, not `=`.)

Ado parameters do not have an `AsString` or `AsValue` property.  They are of type `TParameter`, defined in AdoDB.Pas as

```
 TParameter = class(TCollectionItem)
  [...]
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    procedure AppendChunk(Val: OleVariant);
    procedure LoadFromFile(const FileName: string; DataType: TDataType);
    procedure LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream; DataType: TDataType);
    property ParameterObject: _Parameter read GetParameter;
    property Parameters: TParameters read GetParameters;
    property Properties: Properties read GetProperties;
  published
    property Name: WideString read GetName write SetName;
    property Attributes: TParameterAttributes read GetAttributes write SetAttributes default [];
    property DataType: TDataType read GetDataType write SetDataType default ftUnknown;
    property Direction: TParameterDirection read GetParameterDirection write SetParameterDirection default pdInput;
    property NumericScale: Byte read GetNumericScale write SetNumericScale default 0;
    property Precision: Byte read GetPrecision write SetPrecision default 0;
    property Size: Integer read GetSize write SetSize default 0;
    property Value: Variant read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;
```

**Update** I can tell from your comments that there is a certain amount of confusion.  Perhaps this will help:

Suppose you have a Names table with an AName field and you want to find the row with the value
'Me' in the AName field.

The following code will do it:

```
AdoConnection1.Connected := True;
AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from [Names] where AName = :AName';
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('AName').Value := 'Me';
AdoQuery1.Open;
```

In the SQL.Text, `:AName` is simply a placeholder for the parameter in the query.
The convention is that the text following the ':' is the name of the table column,
but it doesn't have to be, any valid Sql name will do, as in

```
AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from [Names] where AName = :Something';
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Something').Value := 'Me';
```

Comment: I corrected the previous syntaxe mistake ans now another message showed up :"Classe exception EDatabaseError with message 'AdoQuery1 :parameters '@nom_util' not found"

Comment: Given paarameterised Sql like 'select * from SomeTable where Name = :Name`, the parameter name would be 'Name', not '@Name'.

Comment: What about the parameter value, do I define @ or just leave it blank?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean.  If you write the Sql like I quoted it, the placeholder for the parameter isn't a blank, it's the ':Name'.

Comment: by that I mean adoQuery/parameters/value, do I leave it blank?

Comment: I didn't mean parameter/name

Comment: What is the "it" you are referring to in "do I leave it blank?"

Comment: @Ash read Embarcadero's documentation: [Using Parameters in Queries](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries) and [Handling Command Parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Handling_Command_Parameters)

Comment: So, has this answered your q?  If not, what difficulty are you still having?